# Table not refreshing after post function in JQuery and ASP.NET CORE

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, entity-framework

I have made a filtering method. This method is working like a charm and when I type something the table updates to the search string. This is my method for the search:

```
loadList() {
var searchString = $(".search-input").val();
$.post('/Translation/List?searchString=' + searchString, function (data) {                      
$(".table-content-view").html(data);                    
});
}
```

And when I wanna insert a new record I call this method:

```
saveTranslation() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Translation/Edit',
                    data: new FormData($(`${tr.selectedclass} #translation-form`)[0]),
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response.success === true) {                        
                            loadList();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

This method works fine (confirmed with postman and chrome dev tools). The problem is I need to press F5 to see the new record instead that it refresh instantly. As you can see I call the method `LoadList()` to refresh the table but this doesn't work.

NOTE:

I use a partial view for the table.

This is my C# method for the list:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> List(string searchString)
{       
    var translations = _context.translation.AsQueryable();
    translations = translations.OrderBy(x => x.CORETRANSLATIONID);

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
           translations = translations.Where(x => x.ORIGINAL.Contains(searchString));
    }           
    return PartialView(await translations.ToListAsync());
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: does response.success returns true

Comment: I just deleted the if statement and now it is working good!

Comment: @Fearcoder I suggest to don't delete the if statement but add else statement and inside this else return all records

Comment: @Fearcoder instead of deleting questions you should provide explanations when asked. `Restrict` will throw in EF Core 2.x if you try to delete a parent entity, so there's no need to add your own check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my **post** method in JQuery I changed it too

```
saveTranslation() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Translation/Edit',
                    data: new FormData($(`${tr.selectedclass} #translation-form`)[0]),
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function (response) {                      
                        loadList();
                    }
                });
            }
```

The if statement was not necessary.